# How to convert s3Object into File and send it inside a FormData on nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

so I need to download a file from S3 bucket and then, with either its buffer or readStream, append it to a FormData on **node**. I've tried different libraries such as [formdata-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node), [isomorphic-form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-form-data) and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data). Only **formdata-node** printed a FormData type on the log, while still having no values attached to it, and the others crashed as soon as I tried to instantiate a FormData.

[image: log displaying empty FormData]

```
const form = new FormData();
      form.set("UsuarioInclusaoDR", body.UsuarioInclusaoDR);
      form.set(
        "TipoDocumentoDigitalizadoDR",
        body.TipoDocumentoDigitalizadoDR
      );
      form.set(
        "DescDocumentoDigitalizado",
        body.DescDocumentoDigitalizado
      );
      form.set("TipoDocumento", fileType);
      form.set("NomeDocumento", file.originalname);
      form.set("Documento", {
        name: file.originalname,
        [Symbol.toStringTag]: "File",
        stream() {
          return s3Object;
        },
      });
```

I've tried removing the "Documento" form.set and it also didn't work. Any clues on what's impeding my FormData to get values set, or appended (i've tried both?)

Also, I'm really struggling trying to get a valid File from my S3 Buffer, is there any way to do that?